# What is the best data type suitable for integers with max limit upto 10^5?

Tags: c, types, int, limit, unsigned-integer

In reference to INPUT section of

http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL

What data type should I use for value of t?
Also, do int vs unsigned int take same processing overhead?

Comment: Since you are not using the value `T` for any expensive operation, and just for reading number of `BTSes`, `int` should do the trick here.

Comment: About the processing cost, that will depend on the platform/processor.

Answer (score 0):

In C the best recommendation for integers 0 to 100,000 would be
type:

If best means speed: `uint_fast32_t`

If best means space: `uint_least32_t`.

`int` is 2 bytes on some machines.  If portability is important, consider that.

---

Significant processing differences, *in general*, do not exist for `signed` vs. `unsigned`.  With select compilers/optimization/machines certain commands (right-shift, divide, etc.)  *may* be significantly different and profiling is the best determination.

Comment: Not true, only if its generalized for major desktop platforms (like x86).

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento  I've worked with a number of embedded processors found unsigned vs signed performance similar there too.  Maybe an old 6502 may have unsigned trouble, but nothing I've used in the last 10 years.  Suggest you post answer with your C solution.

Comment: There's no solution for what is not a problem. Your response is good, but yes there's embedded processor that will take more instructions to work with unsigned/signed. Anyway I think this is not the case of the OP.

Comment: I am a beginner in C. Can you tell me where (any references) to read about these data types in its most easily understandable form.

Comment: @fakeprogrammer Welcome to SO.  "most easily understandable form" - that is highly subjective and another question.  There are _many_ places such as http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html.  Of course, one can search for "ISO/IEC 9899:201x draft" and read nearly the best definition.